# compilation errors in java language

Tags: java, compilation, extends

Hi I have Library class is not finished , I get compilation problems in Library class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Library {
    // Add the missing implementation to this class

    public static void printOpeningHours(){
        System.out.println("Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm.");

    }
    public void printAddress(){
        System.out.println("10 Main St.");
        System.out.println("228 Liberty St.");

    }
    public void borrowBook(){
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String x=sc.nextLine();
        if (x=firstLibrary){
        System.out.println("You successfully borrowed The Lord of the Rings");
        firstLibrary.remove("The Lord of the Ring");
        }else if{
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
        }else (x=secondLibrary){
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
        }

    }
    public static void printAvailableBooks(){
        return firstLibrary;
        return secondLibrary;
    }
    public void returnBook(){
        firstLibrary.add("The Lord of the Ring");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
         Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St.");
         Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St."); 

        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities"));
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings"));

        // Print opening hours and the addresses
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Library addresses:");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries
        System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:");
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library
        System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of available from the first library
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
    }
}
```

the output of Library class should be like this :

```
Library hours:
Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm.
Library addresses:
10 Main St.
228 Liberty St.
Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:
You successfully borrowed The Lord of the Rings
Sorry, this book is already borrowed.
Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.
Books available in the first library:
The Da Vinci Code
Le Petit Prince
A Tale of Two Cities
Books available in the second library:
No book in catalog
Returning The Lord of the Rings:
You successfully returned The Lord of the Rings
Books available in the first library:
The Da Vinci Code
Le Petit Prince
A Tale of Two Cities
The Lord of the Rings
```

I get compilation error in borrowBook() and printAvailableBooks() and returnBook() ... The main method must not modify ...

How to correct the code of following methods : borrowBook() and printAvailableBooks() and returnBook() ?

many thanks :)

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: That's a terrible title. Please change it to reflect the actual issue(s).

Comment: for example in printAvailableBooks() method eclipse says : firstLibrary cannot be resolved to a variable ...

Comment: ok brother what title do you suggest ... peace

Comment: One that reflects the actual issue(s).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `borrowBook()`, you have an `if`, then an `else`, then an `else if`. The `else` should always come last:

```
if (x=firstLibrary){
    System.out.println("You successfully borrowed The Lord of the Rings");
    firstLibrary.remove("The Lord of the Ring");
} else if (x=secondLibrary){
    System.out.println("Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
}
```

`firstLibrary` and `secondLibrary` don't exist in `Library`, but I'm guessing you haven't added it yet.

In `printAvailableBooks()` you have two `return` statements back-to-back. The second one will never be reached. Also, if you're just trying to print them, use
`System.out.println()`.

`returnBook()` will also fail because `firstLibrary` doesn't exist (same reason as `borrowBook()`.

Also, I would not make Library extend Book. Just think of it logically without relating it to programming. A library is not a book. A library has books, so maybe you have some variable in Library that holds a collection of Books.

Comment: thank you .. I did change places of else and else if .. in printAvailableBooks() method eclipse says : firstLibrary cannot be resolved to a variable ... do you know how to correct it??

Comment: First of all, I'd suggest you go through the latest edition of Java: A Beginner's Guide. There are a ton of errors in your code that suggest you are a Java beginner (nothing wrong with that, we all started there!). A lot of your questions could be solved by going through that book.

Comment: thank you .. do you know how to correct printAvailableBooks() method ?

Comment: `firstLibrary` cannot be resolved because it is not a variable in your `Library` class. It looks like you might be trying to refer to the `firstLibrary` variable in your main method, which won't work.

Comment: If you want to print the books in the library, you'll need to maintain a `List` of `Book` objects. `addBook()` should add a `Book` to the list, and `printAvailableBooks()` should iterate over the list and use `System.out.println()` to print the books out. There is a lot more implementation and refactoring that needs to be done, so I'd go read through that book to better understand the language and how it works.

Comment: Not sure who down-voted this and why. Could you maybe accept my answer and upvote if it was helpful?

Comment: thank you brother it was helpful ... who to accept your answers and upvote?

Comment: Clicking the up arrow next to my answer upvotes it (not sure if you can with your reputation), while clicking the green check mark accepts it.

Comment: I can not upvote it but I accepted it ... So do you think that my if sats is correct in the borrowBook() method ... am I on the right path ?